# Loss of data when trying to input to multiple tables (DISCUSSION)

Tags: mysql, sql

**PROBLEM:**
Hello, I have created a DBMS for one my client in which there is a functionality of values get split to four different tables from the same form input (but) Sometimes it happens that values get input to table1 and table2 and not to table3 and table4 due to which it results to errors with the calculations of values. I did a check on it and found out this problem usually occur when the connection is slow or online server is down.

**SOLUTION:** Kindly let me know how can i make my solution much effective so it'll not result to loss of data (just need a hint/logic). One solution is in my mind is that if i embed the insertion to all the table in one sql query (currently the insertion query for each table is separate) then  it may  will resolve the issue (Can you please give me a hint how can i make insertion to multiple tables with one SQL query i'll very appreciate that)

THANKS

Comment: Use transactions to avoid data errors during inserts/updates to multiple tables

Answer (score 0):

Try using transactions to ensure that changes are only committed if inserts into all tables succeed.

[Transactions in MySQL](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3382171/Transactions-in-MySQL.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a transaction: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html